# Why is my approach to this problem about charging an uncharged capacitor with a charged capacitor wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, capacitance

This is the above mentioned problem : 
 
Using a battery a10 pF capacitor is charged to 50V and then the battery is removed. After
that, a second uncharged capacitor is connected to the first capacitor in parallel. If the final
voltage across the second capacitor is 20V , its capacitance is _________ pF .
I approached the problem like this; the energy lost by the capacitor in the process of reducing its potential to 20V, must be gained by the uncharged capacitor{$\frac 12C_1\Delta(V^2)=\frac 12 C_2V_2^2$ where $\Delta(V^2)=V_1^2-V_2^2$}. 
 I would be grateful if someone could point out the error in this approach. Also, I am aware that this problem can be solved with conservation of charge principle.

Comment: I don't think that it is a stupid question but the problem is subtle.  You have shown that if it comes to equilibrium then this would be it.  However, you have not shown that it comes to an equilibrium.  This often happens in maths when calculating limits.  If you assume but don't prove that a limit exists then you might get a nonsense answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, energy is not conserved in this situation because some energy is eventually lost as Joule heat in the wires, even if the wire resistance is very small.

Comment: But usually we consider ideal conditions where no energy loss has occurred right? I mean unless I explicitly introduce external factors, this equation shouldn't wrong... I think...

Comment: @Schrödinger'sDolphin : In this situation, if there is no energy loss, there is no equilibrium: currents will persist. If one assumes both that the system eventually comes to equilibrium and energy is conserved, one gets a violation of charge conservation, which is not good.

Comment: Thankyou Sir this was a very stupid question. Welp

Comment: Actually it's not stupid at all. I've used one like it at university admissions interviews. It's worth mentioning the reason currents persist is that the connection gives an RLC circuit which oscillates forever if R is zero.   C is specified, and L must be nonzero (though small) because you've made a circuit.